# Once I attach a second display, when I then start my laptop without it, mouse cursor is invisible (but works). How to fix?

Tags: xorg, mouse, graphics, intel-graphics

Once I use an external CRT display (explicitly disabling it before shutting down does not help) with my laptop, then when I next start my laptop without any external display attached, mouse cursor is invisible (but works, i still can click buttons, but can't track where the cursor is now). How to fix this?

I use Ubuntu (classic Gnome version) 10.10 on Toshiba L10 with Intel 82852/855GM graphics. When I was using Arch Linux with XFCE, there used to be the same problem.

I've tried disabling Metacity's (and XFWM in past) composition, explicitly disabling external monitor, changing mouse cursor, updating drivers several times, nothing seems to help, I always have to have an external monitor attached (I may disable it, but it has to be attached) at boot time if I want to see my mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that I have used is switching to a TTY `(Ctrl+Alt+F1 - Ctrl+Alt+F6)` and switching back to the desktop `(Ctrl+Alt+F7)`.

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't work. Ctrl+F1..F4 and Ctrl+F7 do nothing. Ctrl+F5 closes all the web pages opened, Ctrl+F6 selects the whole URL in the address bar. Obviously, these keys are processed by current active application and are not meant to control X. Alt+F# keys don't do anything useful either.

Comment: Oops. I left the wrong shortcut. Add "Alt" to the shortcuts.

Comment: This does not help anyway :-( After switching to TTY and back to the desktop a mouse cursor is still invisible.